# How can I make a Shiny app W3C compliant?

Tags: html, r, shiny

I've written and optimized a *Shiny app*, and now I'm struggling with the IT section of the organization where I work to have it published on their servers.
Currently, they are claiming that the app is not W3C compliant, which is true, according to the [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/).

The errors I'm trying to solve, with no success, are:

- `<form class="well" role="complementary">` Bad value “complementary” for attribute “role” on element “form”.
- `<label class="control-label" id="foo-label" for="foo">` The value of the “for” attribute of the “label” element must be the ID of a non-hidden form control.

Such errors can be seen also in very minimal shiny apps, like:

```
# Reprex adapted from https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/tabsets.html
library(shiny)

# Define UI for random distribution app ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Tabsets"),
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      
      # Input: Select the random distribution type ----
      radioButtons("dist", "Distribution type:",
                   c("Normal" = "norm",
                     "Uniform" = "unif",
                     "Log-normal" = "lnorm",
                     "Exponential" = "exp")),
      
      # br() element to introduce extra vertical spacing ----
      br(),
      
      # Input: Slider for the number of observations to generate ----
      sliderInput("n",
                  "Number of observations:",
                  value = 500,
                  min = 1,
                  max = 1000)
      
    ),
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      
      # Output: Tabset w/ plot, summary, and table ----
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot")),
                  tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary")),
                  tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table"))
      )
      
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic for random distribution app ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Reactive expression to generate the requested distribution ----
  d <- reactive({
    dist <- switch(input$dist,
                   norm = rnorm,
                   unif = runif,
                   lnorm = rlnorm,
                   exp = rexp,
                   rnorm)
    
    dist(input$n)
  })
  
  # Generate a plot of the data ----
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    dist <- input$dist
    n <- input$n
    
    hist(d(),
         main = paste("r", dist, "(", n, ")", sep = ""),
         col = "#75AADB", border = "white")
  })
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The second error seems to be related, somehow, to *radiobuttons* only, whereas the first one seems to afflict all the *shiny apps* I've found on the web and tested with the W3C validator so far.
For completeness, I report also the HTML code generated by the shiny app in the reprex:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <script type="application/shiny-singletons"></script>
  <script type="application/html-dependencies">jquery[3.6.0];shiny-css[1.7.1];shiny-javascript[1.7.1];ionrangeslider-javascript[2.3.1];strftime[0.9.2];ionrangeslider-css[2.3.1];bootstrap[3.4.1]</script>
<script src="shared/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="shared/shiny.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="shared/shiny.min.js"></script>
<script src="shared/ionrangeslider/js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>
<script src="shared/strftime/strftime-min.js"></script>
<link href="shared/ionrangeslider/css/ion.rangeSlider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link href="shared/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="shared/bootstrap/accessibility/css/bootstrap-accessibility.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="shared/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="shared/bootstrap/accessibility/js/bootstrap-accessibility.min.js"></script>  <title>Tabsets</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h2>Tabsets</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <form class="well" role="complementary">
          <div id="dist" class="form-group shiny-input-radiogroup shiny-input-container" role="radiogroup" aria-labelledby="dist-label">
            <label class="control-label" id="dist-label" for="dist">Distribution type:</label>
            <div class="shiny-options-group">
              <div class="radio">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="dist" value="norm" checked="checked"/>
                  <span>Normal</span>
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="radio">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="dist" value="unif"/>
                  <span>Uniform</span>
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="radio">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="dist" value="lnorm"/>
                  <span>Log-normal</span>
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="radio">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="dist" value="exp"/>
                  <span>Exponential</span>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br/>
          <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
            <label class="control-label" id="n-label" for="n">Number of observations:</label>
            <input class="js-range-slider" id="n" data-skin="shiny" data-min="1" data-max="1000" data-from="500" data-step="1" data-grid="true" data-grid-num="9.99" data-grid-snap="false" data-prettify-separator="," data-prettify-enabled="true" data-keyboard="true" data-data-type="number"/>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8" role="main">
        <div class="tabbable">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabsetid="9747">
            <li class="active">
              <a href="#tab-9747-1" data-toggle="tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-value="Plot">Plot</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#tab-9747-2" data-toggle="tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-value="Summary">Summary</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#tab-9747-3" data-toggle="tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-value="Table">Table</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="tab-content" data-tabsetid="9747">
            <div class="tab-pane active" data-value="Plot" id="tab-9747-1">
              <div id="plot" class="shiny-plot-output" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" data-value="Summary" id="tab-9747-2">
              <pre class="shiny-text-output noplaceholder" id="summary"></pre>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" data-value="Table" id="tab-9747-3">
              <div id="table" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks!

---

This message was also posted on [RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/make-a-shiny-app-w3c-compliant/130250): sorry for cross-posting.

Comment: Maybe check out this tutorial on modifying HTML elements: https://youtu.be/jVh05izjHMI

Comment: I am probably being a bit naive on this, but (besides you needing to get it done for this scenario), in general what are the advantages for being W3C compliant?

Comment: I have no idea about the detailed justifications for the rules, but presumably someone thought about them carefully?  https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/ says that the only allowed roles for `form` are `Roles: search, none or presentation`

Comment: [This article](https://www.polemicdigital.com/w3c-compliance-is-it-a-requirement/) makes the argument that the effort of hunting down each w3c violation might not be worth it. As long as the list of violations is not super long, maybe you can instead test cross-browser compatibility yourself? Not sure if that'll convince your IT colleagues though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following only deals with the first of the errors you mention (as this one is pretty clear thanks to @BenBolkers comment), but hopefully it points you to the right tools to use.

I'd use [htmltools::tagQuery](https://rstudio.github.io/htmltools/articles/tagQuery.html) to make the needed modifications - please check the following:

```
# Reprex adapted from https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/tabsets.html
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)

# Define UI for random distribution app ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Tabsets"),
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    {querySidebarPanel <- tagQuery(sidebarPanel(
      # Input: Select the random distribution type ----
      radioButtons("dist", "Distribution type:",
                   c("Normal" = "norm",
                     "Uniform" = "unif",
                     "Log-normal" = "lnorm",
                     "Exponential" = "exp")),
      
      # br() element to introduce extra vertical spacing ----
      br(),
      
      # Input: Slider for the number of observations to generate ----
      sliderInput("n",
                  "Number of observations:",
                  value = 500,
                  min = 1,
                  max = 1000)
    ))
    querySidebarPanel$find(".well")$removeAttrs("role")$addAttrs("role" = "none")$allTags()},
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      
      # Output: Tabset w/ plot, summary, and table ----
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot")),
                  tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary")),
                  tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table"))
      )
      
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic for random distribution app ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Reactive expression to generate the requested distribution ----
  d <- reactive({
    dist <- switch(input$dist,
                   norm = rnorm,
                   unif = runif,
                   lnorm = rlnorm,
                   exp = rexp,
                   rnorm)
    
    dist(input$n)
  })
  
  # Generate a plot of the data ----
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    dist <- input$dist
    n <- input$n
    
    hist(d(),
         main = paste("r", dist, "(", n, ")", sep = ""),
         col = "#75AADB", border = "white")
  })
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Please also see this [related chapter](https://unleash-shiny.rinterface.com/htmltools-overview.html#htmltools-modern) from *"Outstanding User Interfaces with Shiny"*.