# R Shiny selectizeInput Accessibility Missing Form Label

Tags: r, shiny, accessibility

Say for example, I have a very basic shiny application where you selectize a letter:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(3, selectizeInput("Letters", "Choose a Letter",
      choices = LETTERS, multiple = TRUE)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: Basic UI]

I need this shiny application to be 508 compliant/accessible.  If I run it through a web accessibility test like [WAVE](https://wave.webaim.org/), I get an error about a Missing form label for this selectizeInput section.

[image: Missing Form Label]

I believe this is because of a random div that is added that does not have the same ID that the "Choose a letter" label references.  The label is for `Letters-selectized` and the div that is showing an accessibility error has the ID `Letters`.  Is there any way to fix this error?  I know you can add `render` to the options for selectizeInput but I havent found a way to correct this particular div.

Based on comment from [ismirsehregal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9841389/ismirsehregal)
If I try to add an additional label with `tagQuery` for the ID "Letters", I get a duplicate form label error. I believe this is because even though I specify `"for" = "Letters"` the output is still `for = "Letters-selectized"`

```
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)

ui <- fluidPage(
  {queryfluidRow <- tagQuery(fluidRow(
    column(3, selectizeInput("Letters", "Choose a Letter",
      choices = LETTERS, multiple = TRUE))
    )
  )
  queryfluidRow$find("#Letters")$parent()$prepend(tag("label hidden",list("class" = "control-label","for" = "Letters", "Custom Tag")))$allTags()}
)

server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The added tagQuery label html looks like the following and produces additional errors.  I probably do not understand the underlying html relationship between labels and form control selection.  However, I would have assumed setting `"for" = "Letters"` in `tagQuery` would have assigned the label to the correct ID:

```
<label hidden="" class="control-label" for="Letters-selectized">Custom Tag</label>
<select id="Letters" class="form-control selectized shiny-bound-input" multiple="multiple" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;"></select>
```

Comment: Maybe you can adjust things via htmltools::tagQuery. Please see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71348276/9841389).

Comment: @ismirsehregal added an attempt of adjusting using tagQuery but the control-label is still not linking with the missing form control

Comment: The generated code at the end of your question isn't right. I'm not a R/Shiny developer, but from an HTML accessibility perspective, the ID referenced in the `<label for="ID">` must match the ID of the `<select>`.  You have `<label for="Letters-selectized">` but the ID on the `<select>` is `<select id="Letters">`.

Comment: @slugolicious yes I believe that's the problem i'm trying to solve.  In the R code i define "for" = "Letters" with `tag("label hidden",list("class" = "control-label","for" = "Letters", "Custom Tag"))` but something in the backend transforms that into for= "Letters-selectized" and I don't understand why that's happening.

Answer (score 1):

{[shinyjs](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs)} allows you i. a. to execute javascript code client-side. You can thus query your label element via its id and set its `for` attribute like so:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),  # include shinyjs
  fluidRow(
    column(3, selectizeInput("Letters", "Choose a Letter",
      choices = LETTERS, multiple = TRUE)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  runjs('document.getElementById("Letters-label").setAttribute("for", "letters")')
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

BTW, apart from above library, **[Shiny Awesome](https://github.com/nanxstats/awesome-shiny-extensions)** lists many more, well, awesome extensions for Shiny apps. Kudos to [Nan Xiao](https://github.com/nanxstats).

Comment: Thanks for this, I think your proposed solution creates duplicate form label errors.  However, i believe this is fixed if I instead add an aria-labelledby attribute to Letters `runjs('document.getElementById("Letters").setAttribute("aria-labelledby", "Letters-selectized")')`